# Twitter Button, share tweets

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, share, share-button, twitter-button

I hope, I can write tweet like this:

`some text Lorem ipsum #myhastag Duis efficitur risus et augue tempus tristique`.

so the format is : `text #hashtag text`.

so in html I wrote,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Lorem ipsum&button_hashtag=myhashtag&text= Duis efficitur risus et augue tempus tristique." target="_blank" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-show-count="false">SHARE</a>
```

But, the result just

```
Lorem ipsum #myhashtag
```

I have searched on https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button and youtube video tutorial but still no idea.

I hope someone can help me, write tweet with format

```
text #hashtag text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [Percent Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the hash symbol as `%23`

Try this:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text%20%23hashtag%20more%20text

Comment: Cool. If I've helped, please click the accept button (The Tick).